# Deeplinking specifics to PayPal app to send/request money from an account?

Tags: ios, react-native, paypal, deep-linking

**Situation:**

I'm currently developing an app that links users to their payment processing platform applications.

*This takes for granted the user already has the payment processing app downloaded already.*

I wanted to make transactions easier between them by opening the app and taking them to the other user's send/request page; with it already having set the money agreed between the two.

This is the function I am opening the deep links with:

```
const openLink = (url) => Linking.openURL(url)
```

I have been successful creating specific with both Cash App and Venmo, as seen below.

Cash App Example:

```
https://cash.app/$UserAccount/MoneyAmount
```

Venmo Example:

```
venmo://paycharge?txn=pay&recipients=UserAccount&amount=MoneyAmount
```

**Problem:**

I have not figured out PayPal's configuration for it.

**What I've Got So Far:**

Using the below allows the user to open the PayPal App:

```
paypal://
```

However, I searched and still had no idea what parameters the deep link url accepts, even trying the previous examples to try and replicate it.

**Specs:**

```
Hardware: iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015)
OS: MacOS Big Sur 
Main Dependency: "react-native": "^0.63.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is less of an answer and more of a conclusion of this topic.

I contacted developer support for PayPal with this post copy-pasted to it. They replied that they do not support deep linking.